# Iterating in dropdown-menu

Tags: python, selenium

i'm having some troubles with trying to get a list in python..

I'm using Selenium Web Driver, Chrome specifically, and i have the next "button" :

```
<button id="btn" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Nope</button>
<ul id="ulDropdownNivel2" class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">text1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">text2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">text3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So.. i have tried to use Select.class of Selenium Wd but, it's a button, and the class can't be used there... tried using it on the `<ul>` but it can't use Select neither...

Can't use smh like:

```
dropdoun = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('ID'))
for elm in dropdoun{ print(elm.text())}
```

Tried to figure a way to iterate through items... but i didn't get anything

i figured a way to click by xPath but, it doesn't work to me, cause text1, text2, text3 and so changes the order everytime you open the web

Any idea?

EDIT:

What i need here, is to iterate trough each item, and select the one that match with "text1", "text2" or "text3...

Comment: what you want to do is not clear. i understand you want to click on one of the items but you need to check its content in order to click the right one. but you haven't said anything about that check. could you update your question?

Comment: It would be great if you can clarify your question and what you wants to exactly achieve.

Comment: @bobrobbob .. There i updated my question...

What i need to do here, is to iterate trough each item, and select the one that match with "text1", "text2" or "text3...

Comment: @IshitaShah There i updated my question... What i need to do here, is to iterate trough each item, and select the one that match with "text1", "text2" or "text3..

Comment: @knowledgefirst Your question is not clear to understand, Why you want to iterate ?  What you want to exactly match  and click ?

Comment: Lets say this... i have to match inner text of a certain item in the menu/list and click/select it.   But each item varies it position on the list.. That's why i don't select it by index. @IshitaShah

Answer (score 0):

I think you should click button for dropdown will be opened:

```
opendropdownButton = driver.find_element_by_id("btn").click()

//here should be wait if now works 
dropdownElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul [@id="ulDropdownNivel2"]//a")
for elm in dropdownElements{ print(elm.text())}
```